# Check if a word from one file exists in another file and print the matching line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which is having some specific words. I have another file having the URLs which contains that word from file1.

I would like to print url if each word in file1 matches with file2. If word is not found in file2 then return "no matching"

I tried with Awk and `grep` and used `if` conditions also. But did not get expected results.

File1:

```
abc 
Def
XYZ
```

File2:

```
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux2.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux3.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_xyz_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_xyz_linux2.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_def_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_def_linux2.git
```

Output can be like:

```
abc:
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux2.git
Xyz:
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_xyz_linux1.git
```

Etc..

Tried:

```
file=/bin/file1.txt

for i in `cat $file1`;
do
a=$i
echo "$a:" | awk '$repos.txt ~ $a {printf $?}'
done
```

Tried some other ways like if condition with `grep` and all... but no luck.

`abc` means it should only search for `abc`, not `abcd`.

Comment: Single quotes prevent variable interpolation. Awk doesn't know which shell variables you have; the two are completely separate. Where do you hope `$repos` is coming from?

Comment: If file2 contained `Https://gitlab.private.com/abc-team/mi_pqr_linux1.git` should that match the `abc` from file1 or not? How about `Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abcd_linux1.git`? It's important for you to tell us if you only want to exactly match a string between the 2 `_`s in the final part of the path or anywhere in the line or something else and show examples that demonstrate those requirements. It's always easy to match what you want but harder to not match similar strings you don't want.

Comment: I need to match that exact name.. anyways, those names are based on the url only. abc means it should only search for abc not abcd

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your attempt is pretty far from the mark. Probably learn the basics of the shell and Awk before you proceed.

Here is a simple implementation which avoids [reading lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

```
while IFS='' read -r word; do
    echo "$word:"
    grep -F "$word" File2
done <File1
```

If you want to match case-insensitively, use `grep -iF`.

The requirement to avoid substring matches is a complication. The `-w` option to `grep` nominally restrics matching to entire words, but the definition of "word" characters includes the underscore character, so you can't use that directly. A manual approximation might look like

```
    grep -iE "(^|[^a-z])$word([^a-z]|$)" File2
```

but this might not work with all `grep` implementations.

A better design is perhaps to prefix the match(es) before each output line, and only loop over the input file once.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { w[a] = "(^|[^a-z])" $0 "([^a-z]|$)"; next }
    { m = "" 
      for (a in w) if ($0 ~ w[a]) m = m (m ? "," : "") a
      if (m) print m ":" $0 }' File1 File2
```

In brief, we collect the search words in the array `w` from the first input file. When reading the second input file, we collect matches on all the search words in `m`; if `m` is non-empty, we print its value followed by the input line which matched.

Again, if you want case-insensitive matching, use `tolower()` where appropriate.

Demo, featuring lower-case comparisons: https://ideone.com/iTWpFn

Comment: I put while inside while and put a if condition like while IFS=' ' read -r string; do while IFS=' ' read -r string2; do echo "$string2:" if [[ $string == *"$string2"*]]; then echo "$string" fi done < file2 done < file1... it is working but only doing operation on first word in the file1.. please suggest what went wrong

Comment: The above while statement given by you is also working only for the 1st word in the file1.. but not checking for the other words in file1.. please suggest

Comment: Your sample data doesn't contain any matches on the last two search words. If you want to match case-insensitively, use `grep -iF`. In the shell loop, probably convert both strings to lower case in the comparison; see [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html); look for the `,,` operator (which however requires Bash 4+).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want case-insensitive matching.

An awk solution:

```
$ cat <<'EOD' >file1
abc
Def
XYZ
missing
EOD
$ cat <<'EOD' >file2
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux2.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux3.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_xyz_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_xyz_linux2.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_def_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_def_linux2.git
EOD
$ awk '
    # create lowercase versions
    {
        lc = tolower($0)
    }

    # loop over lines of file1
    # store search strings in array
    # key is search string, value will be results found
    NR==FNR {
        h[lc]
        next
    }

    # loop over lines of file2
    # if search string found, append line to results
    {
        for (s in h)
            if (lc ~ s)
                h[s] = h[s]"\n"$0
    }

    # loop over seearch strings and print results
    # if no result, show error message
    END {
        for (s in h)
            print s":"( h[s] ? h[s] : "\nno matching" )
    }
' file1 file2
missing:
no matching
def:
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_def_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_def_linux2.git
abc:
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux2.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_abc_linux3.git
xyz:
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_xyz_linux1.git
Https://gitlab.private.com/apm-team/mi_xyz_linux2.git
$
```